# Difference between checkout+merge and pull

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose that on my git repo we have two branches:

1. Master
2. Test

On my local repo, I am currently on Master and I want to merge the updated version of Test.

What I would do is:

```
git checkout Test
git pull
git checkout Master
git merge Test
```

(probably the second line is useless..)

As far as I understand, this line:

```
git pull origin Test
```

*(in the first version this was "git pull origin/Test", thanks to @Tim to fix this)*

**should** get my Master branch to a similar state (i.e., it will include changes from Test).
I know that *pull* equals to *fetch+merge*, so I am a bit confused now.

The question is: what is the difference between the two approaches above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following command from the `Master` branch:

```
git pull origin Test
```

avoids having to change branches to `Test` just in order to pull.  It is equivalent to this:

```
git fetch origin Test && git merge origin/Test
```

But the kicker is that Git will only do the merge if the merge can be done via a fast forward.  If that's *not* possible, then you would have to do an explicit merge.

I can offer the following workflow as an alternative to `git pull origin Test`:

```
# from Master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/Test
```

The above two-liner updates the local tracking branch `origin/Test` with the latest changes from the remote.  Then, it merges `Test` directly into your `Master` branch.  Note that we did not have to switch branches away from `Master`; the entire merge was possible without doing a `git checkout`.  And Git will always merge with this approach, even if that merge would result in conflicts.

Comment: Can you run "git pull origin Test" from the local **Master** branch? And in this case, what will happen?

Comment: @Desmond I edited my answer based on your recent edits.  My suggested approach did not change.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's equivalent to `git fetch origin Test; git merge origin/Test`—i.e., it uses the updated remote-tracking `origin/Test` reference. (In Git versions predating 1.8.4, this specific kind of `git fetch` fails to update `origin/Test` so you must use `git merge FETCH_HEAD` instead, but we might be able to assume Git >= 2.0, for instance.)

Comment: @torek Thanks, that was a typo.  Didn't know that the 2.0 version would work.  Good to see you again.